Java Azure function in MacOS M1 does not work when running locally with Maven or IntelliJ and does not show logs but it does work with C#
I'm working with a MacOS M1 and I'm trying to create an Azure function using Java and Maven.
I've followed all the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij
And also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java?tabs=macos%2Cbash%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser
That is to say, I've configured the JAVA_HOME environment to point to my JDK 11 version, etc. and tried to run the Azure function both in IntelliJ and with mvn azure-functions:run command.
In both cases I don't get any error but the only logs I can see are the following:
Extension bundle specified, skip install extension

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

It's very weird because it doesn't seem to be running the func start command or something like that. It's not detecting my Function which is correctly annotated with @FunctionName("HttpTriggerJava") and all other details that the Microsoft Azure documentation states.
On the other hand, if I follow the docs for creating an Azure Function with C# everything works as expected. Following is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=macos%2Cazure-cli
Below are the logs I'm getting after running func start:
Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/LocalFunctionProj/obj/Debug/net8.0/WorkerExtensions/WorkerExtensions.csproj (in 1.91 sec).
  WorkerExtensions -> /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/LocalFunctionProj/obj/Debug/net8.0/WorkerExtensions/buildout/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll
  LocalFunctionProj -> /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/LocalFunctionProj/bin/output/LocalFunctionProj.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:13.89



Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-10-13T19:55:52.679Z] Found /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/LocalFunctionProj/LocalFunctionProj.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-10-13T19:56:00.382Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

    HttpExample: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-10-13T19:56:05.581Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID 

Finally, if I hit the endpoint http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample I'm getting the expected response.
Did anyone experience this issue? I'm stuck with this, I've spent almost the whole day struggling with this and didn't find any solution. I wouldn't want to work with C#.
Thanks in advance

Check if the solution helps.

That solution has not worked for me, I'm getting the same logs as earlier, no azure functions are displayed. I think the issue I'm having is different from the ones you shared with me, I'm not getting any error, I'm simply getting a few logs but Azure Function Tools is not detecting any function, that's it.
I've tried both setting the JAVA_HOME in worker.config.json file and setting the JAVA_HOME directly with JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-17.jdk/Contents/Home mvn azure-functions:run.
None of those workaround worked for me.

Can you share your function code and local.settings.json?

Sure Pravalika KV, here you have:
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
"JAVA_HOME": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.17+8/Contents/Home"
}
}
I've just added JAVA_HOME there, but if I remove it I got the same result.
By the way, thank so much for your help.

Can you add "AzureWebJobsStorage":"UseDevelopmentStorage=true" in local.settings.json and check again

I've already done it. Unfortunately, It doesn't work either

Did you try with any other function triggers(eg: Timer)? Also check the solutions provided here

I've tried earlier the solution provided in that link and it doesn't work either.
About the Timer, I'm getting a different error when trying that. I think I'll go with Python instead of Java, it seems to be working correctly with that language.

Can you try to create and run the project with mvn commands if possible. Also debug the function with command mvn azure-functions:run -X. If it still doesnt work, share your function code.

Yes, I've done it with mvn commands and also with -X parameter and always getting the same result. I cannot paste all the code here, so the most important part is below:
public class HttpTriggerJava {
@FunctionName("HttpTriggerJava")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional> request,
final ExecutionContext context) {
context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
}
}

Change authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous in function code

Oh my god! That was the problem, I don't understand why but just changing what you said it worked correctly!
So, I replaced AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION by AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS and it's working now.
Do you know why it was solved?
Thank you so much!

Ok, If I'm not wrong, it was not showing the existing Function because I was not providing the required function key according with the AuthorizationLevel. FUNCTION, right? Now, since it is ANONYMOUS, it's being showed because nothing is required as a parameter

If you are running the function locally, function key is not required. The function key is necessary when you run the function deployed to Azure.

I was running it locally, so I don’t know why it was expecting the function key. Anyway, thank you so much, I appreciate it your help.

The issue could be due to the way the function core tools handling the Azure function.
As I have mentioned in the comments, change authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous in function code to resolve the issue.
Code Snippet:
@FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
        } else {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
        }
    }

Output:
[INFO] Azure Functions Core Tools found.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)       
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-10-17T14:40:02.210Z] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

Functions:

        HttpExample: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-10-17T14:40:03.163Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2024-10-17T14:40:07.153Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-10-17T14:40:14.300Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpExample' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=3c8dfd9c-92f0-489e-a174-2657eba904d1)
[2024-10-17T14:40:14.449Z] Function "HttpExample" (Id: 3c8dfd9c-92f0-489e-a174-2657eba904d1) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-10-17T14:40:14.449Z] Java HTTP trigger processed a request.
[2024-10-17T14:40:14.585Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpExample' (Succeeded, Id=3c8dfd9c-92f0-489e-a174-2657eba904d1, Duration=316ms)

